# Usage of buttons in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi Everyone I need to have see more button under my testimonial section so that on clicking it should redirect to the page where all the testimonials located.
Please see my images I want button in the place of see more.

[image]

Comment: Why DOWNVOTE???

Comment: Coz Question is simple and it is of basic thing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Magento in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code after your testimonials content `<div>`  and in the `setLocation` give path of your required page.

```
 <button style="width: 98px; overflow: hidden;" type="button" title="SEE MORE" class="button btn-cart"
             onclick="setLocation('#')"><span><span>SEE MORE</span></span></button>
```